# name must be followed by "::" not working after vs error fix suggestion

Tags: c++

Yes, ive googled my problem. here is my code currently:

```
#pragma once
#include "GUI\GUI.h"
#include <filesystem>

using namespace ui;
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

class Settings
{
public:
    void Initialize(MenuMain* pMenuObj);

    void SaveSettings(const std::string& strFileName, MenuMain* pMenuObj);
    void LoadSettings(const std::string& strFileName, MenuMain* pMenuObj);

private:
    void UpdateDirectoryContent(const fs::path& fsPath);
    inline fs::path GetFolderPath();

    fs::path                 fsPath{};
    std::vector<std::string> vecFileNames{};

public:
    /* All our settings variables will be here  *
    * The best would be if they'd get          *
    * initialized in the class itself.         */

    bool  bCheatActive = true;
    bool  bMenuOpened  = false;
    bool  bBhopEnabled = true;
    bool  bShowBoxes   = true;
    bool  bShowNames   = true;
    bool  bShowWeapons = true;
};

extern Settings g_Settings;
```

with an error occuring at `namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem` with `name must be followed by "::" must be class or namespace`

so vs community said that i needed to `#include <filesystem>`, but it was already there.

im not sure entirely what to do here. like i said, ive googled around, and havent found anything to help my problem.

Comment: Make sure to compile it as C++ 17, then check if you can omit the "::experimental" part. What compiler are you using ?

Comment: @ArneJ im using vs community 2019.